# Hiding asp label if gridview return no data

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I hide label if gridvew return no data
I have tried. the below but not sure if it the right approach.

```
<asp:Label runat="server" Text="Device Information " id="DeviceInformation"></asp:Label>



protected void GridView3_DataBound(object senwder, EventArgs e)
{
   int rowCount = GridView3.Rows.Count;

   if (rowCount == 0)
   {
      DeviceInformation.Visible= False;                
   }
   else
   {
     DeviceInformation.Visible= True;
   }
}
```

Any other solution ?

Comment: where are you binding data?

Comment: Your label is part of gridview?

Answer (score 1):

In this case as no rows are there so **RowDataBound** event will not fire as it is fired when adding rows to the **gridview**, you can hide the label at the time of assigning datasource to gridview:

```
gridView1.DataSource = SomeSource;
gridView1.DataBind();

if(gridView1.Rows.Count == 0)
{
 // hide label here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can DataBound event of GridView like this:

```
  protected void gr_DataBound(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
      DeviceInformation.Visible = GridView3.Rows.Count > 0;
    }
```

**Note:** I see that your label is not item of gridview, so I wrote like this. If your label is item of gridview, you should use FindControl method to find and set its visible property.

Answer (score -1):

```
Label lblDeviceInformation = (Label)GridView3.FindControl("DeviceInformation");
int rowCount = GridView3.Rows.Count;
if (rowCount == 0)
{
  lblDeviceInformation .Visible= False;
}
else
{
  lblDeviceInformation .Visible= True;
}
```